# How to use the standalone package in beamer?

Tags: beamer, standalone

I have a beamer presentation that shows a lot of graphs (in the sense
of graph theory) and it takes a lot to compile. I think that the
`standalone` package might help me but I cannot see how. Let us say
this is my main document (I'm using Emacs, and an updated vanilla TeX
Live 2011 in Ubuntu 11.10):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[mode=buildnew]{standalone}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
     %\includestandalone{simpleframe}
     \input{simpleframe}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}

%%% Local Variables:
%%% LaTeX-command: "latex -shell-escape"
%%% End:
```

and this is the file simpleframe.tex:

```
\documentclass[beamer]{standalone}

\begin{document}
  \begin{standaloneframe}
    \only<1>{One}
    \only<2>{Two}
  \end{standaloneframe}
\end{document}
```

Then:

- compiling simpleframe.tex is OK
- compiling the main file is OK as it is
- compiling the main file with `\includestandalone` only shows the
  first overlay, and with overfull boxes.

I would like the advantages of `[mode=buildnew]`, and, isn't true that
for that I need to use `\includestandalone`? How do I do that?

Comment: Does `\usepackage[mode=buildnew,group=false]{standalone}` in the outer document fix it?

Comment: @MikeRenfro No it doesn't, it does not seem to make any
difference. And the manual says about `group=false` that 
"Note that this does not effects the `\includestandalone` 
macro which always will add a group."

Comment: Weird, because I thought I had it working that way. Let me verify.

Comment: @MikeRenfro: No, it's not a grouping issue, but because of the frame content being turned into an image.

Comment: I may have inadvertently triggered a different build path by not having `-shell-escape` enabled. Regardless, I know I had a two-page PDF when I built the outer document, or I was hallucinating.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm the author of `standalone`. First, yes `[mode=buildnew]` needs `\includestandalone`. Files included with `\input` will not be affected by `mode`.
Your problem here is that the standalone file is included as image with this mode and `\includestandalone`. This is done using `\includegraphics` which by default only picks the first page of a multi-page PDF. In order to make this work `\includegraphics` would need to reapply the overlay specifications in the standalone file, i.e. `\includegraphics<1>[page=1]{...}`, `\includegraphics<2>[page=2]{...}`, etc. This is currently not the case, but I will put it on the to-do list for the package.

---

I now created some code which will include all pages of the standalone PDF into beamer. It's just a simple proof-of-concept code and does not support everything, e.g. `\graphicspath` is not supported and the PDF is also not build by `standalone`.

Note that `standalone`s `beamer` support is actually not meant for your application. Having the whole frame as image is not really the way to go. The problem is also that with `beamer` the `standalone` content is not cropped. You might want to look for a better way to improve compiling speed. Have a look at `\includeonlyframes` in the `beamer` manual.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[mode=buildnew]{standalone}

\newcount\mycount
\renewcommand\includestandalone[2][]{%
    \begingroup
    \pdfximage{#2.pdf}%
    \chardef\npages\pdflastximagepages\relax
    \mycount=1
    \loop
        \includegraphics<\the\mycount>[page=\the\mycount,#1]{#2.pdf}
        \ifnum\mycount<\npages
        \advance\mycount by 1
    \repeat
    \endgroup
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
     \includestandalone{simpleframe}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking of producing one pdf for each frame (maybe
multipage if there are overlays) and then the main file would just
concatenate them all (as with `pdfpages`), so I see no need of
cropping. But certainly I would like that when compiling the main file
all modified frames would be built. I do not like the
`\includeonlyframes` way since I would eventually have to compile all
frames anyway. Hmm, if a LaTeX based way is not possible, maybe a
`Makefile` with standalone frames and `pdftk` to concatenate the
`pdf`s could be the way to go...

Comment: Yes, concatenating them with `pdfpages` or a similar tool is a good way here. However, I think then final presentation could be compiled as normal, even if it takes several minutes, only the many compilations during the writing process are usually the culprit.